# Do we have a collocation like "expand leverage"?

Tags: word-choice

I wanna say:

> X country is trying to increase/expand its leverage in (e.g.) Europe.

Is that correct and natural? Which verb should I use? Is any of "expand" or "increase" the right verb to use with leverage by the concept I mean?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on not in and increase not expand.

---

Normally you would not say leverage on not leverage *in*, unless we say *in regard to whatever*.

> The Antarctica Government seems to have substantially more leverage **on** the European Union than the African Congress does , now that large deposits of rare earth metal have been discovered under the ice..

> Antarctica seems to have substantially more leverage, **in** regard to trade subsidies, with the European Union than the African Congress does.

---

Antarctica has limited the yearly production levels of rare earth metals to 2033 levels. Some analysis think *Antarctica is trying to increase its leverage on the European Union* before the resumption of trade talks in Port Stanley.

---

It is an action so you increase or decrease,

> He increased his speed as he pull onto the expressway.

leverage noun [U] (ACTION):the action or advantage of using a lever